# Getting rid of 32-bit native library warning

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, lint

I don't use Android Studio but build my APKs/AABs that use native code through the Android NDK manually by running

```
gradlew build
gradlew bundle
```

on Windows 10 from a command prompt. But whenever I build my app like that, I get this warning:

> WARNING:: This app only has 32-bit [armeabi-v7a] native libraries.
> Beginning August 1, 2019 Google Play store requires that all apps that
> include native libraries must provide 64-bit versions. For more
> information, visit https://g.co/64-bit-requirement

This warning doesn't make any sense at all to me because gradle builds **separate** APKs/AABs for arm7 and arm8 so *of course* app-arm7-release.apk and app-arm7-release.aab do **not** contain any 64-bit libraries because they are, well, 32-bit. The 64-bit libraries are in the other files, i.e. app-arm8-release.apk and app-arm8-release.aab. So why on earth does gradle nag about this? Is there any way to get rid of this warning? It's really annoying me.